# Swagger schema for aws lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, swagger-2.0

I am using AWS version 4 signing process for creating signature for AWS lambda service with API ListFunctions.I am getting correct URL which on postman worked.But when running that python file I am getting 403 status error which tells "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.".Can anyone help me solve the issue?thanks in advance!!

```
python file :

    # Copyright 2010-2018 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
    #
    # This file is licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License").
    # You may not use this file except in compliance with the License. A copy of the
    # License is located at
    #
    # http://aws.amazon.com/apache2.0/
    #
    # This file is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
    # OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
    # language governing permissions and limitations under the License.
    #
    # ABOUT THIS PYTHON SAMPLE: This sample is part of the AWS General Reference 
    # Signing AWS API Requests top available at
    # https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html
    #

    # AWS Version 4 signing example

    # EC2 API (DescribeRegions)

    # See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html
    # This version makes a GET request and passes the signature
    # in the Authorization header.
    import sys, os, base64, datetime, hashlib, hmac 
    import requests # pip install requests

    # ************* REQUEST VALUES *************
    method = 'GET'
    service = 'lambda'
    host = 'lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
    region = 'us-east-1'
    endpoint = 'https://lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions'
    request_parameters = 'Action=ListFunctions&Version=2015-03-31'

    # Key derivation functions. See:
    # http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-python
    def sign(key, msg):
        return hmac.new(key, msg.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()

    def getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName):
        kDate = sign(('AWS4' + key).encode('utf-8'), dateStamp)
        kRegion = sign(kDate, regionName)
        kService = sign(kRegion, serviceName)
        kSigning = sign(kService, 'aws4_request')
        return kSigning

    # Read AWS access key from env. variables or configuration file. Best practice is NOT
    # to embed credentials in code.
    access_key = ""
    secret_key = ""
    if access_key is None or secret_key is None:
        print('No access key is available.')
        sys.exit()

    # Create a date for headers and the credential string
    t = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    amzdate = t.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ')
    datestamp = t.strftime('%Y%m%d') # Date w/o time, used in credential scope


    # ************* TASK 1: CREATE A CANONICAL REQUEST *************
    # http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html

    # Step 1 is to define the verb (GET, POST, etc.)--already done.

    # Step 2: Create canonical URI--the part of the URI from domain to query
    # string (use '/' if no path)
    canonical_uri = '/'

    # Step 3: Create the canonical query string. In this example (a GET request),
    # request parameters are in the query string. Query string values must
    # be URL-encoded (space=%20). The parameters must be sorted by name.
    # For this example, the query string is pre-formatted in the request_parameters variable.
    canonical_querystring = request_parameters

    # Step 4: Create the canonical headers and signed headers. Header names
    # must be trimmed and lowercase, and sorted in code point order from
    # low to high. Note that there is a trailing \n.
    canonical_headers = 'host:' + host + '\n' + 'x-amz-date:' + amzdate + '\n'

    # Step 5: Create the list of signed headers. This lists the headers
    # in the canonical_headers list, delimited with ";" and in alpha order.
    # Note: The request can include any headers; canonical_headers and
    # signed_headers lists those that you want to be included in the
    # hash of the request. "Host" and "x-amz-date" are always required.
    signed_headers = 'host;x-amz-date'

    # Step 6: Create payload hash (hash of the request body content). For GET
    # requests, the payload is an empty string ("").
    payload_hash = hashlib.sha256(('').encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

    # Step 7: Combine elements to create canonical request
    canonical_request = method + '\n' + canonical_uri + '\n' + canonical_querystring + '\n' + canonical_headers + '\n' + signed_headers + '\n' + payload_hash


    # ************* TASK 2: CREATE THE STRING TO SIGN*************
    # Match the algorithm to the hashing algorithm you use, either SHA-1 or
    # SHA-256 (recommended)
    algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'
    credential_scope = datestamp + '/' + region + '/' + service + '/' + 'aws4_request'
    string_to_sign = algorithm + '\n' +  amzdate + '\n' +  credential_scope + '\n' +  hashlib.sha256(canonical_request.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

    # ************* TASK 3: CALCULATE THE SIGNATURE *************
    # Create the signing key using the function defined above.
    signing_key = getSignatureKey(secret_key, datestamp, region, service)

    # Sign the string_to_sign using the signing_key
    signature = hmac.new(signing_key, (string_to_sign).encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()


    # ************* TASK 4: ADD SIGNING INFORMATION TO THE REQUEST *************
    # The signing information can be either in a query string value or in
    # a header named Authorization. This code shows how to use a header.
    # Create authorization header and add to request headers
    authorization_header = algorithm + ' ' + 'Credential=' + access_key + '/' + credential_scope + ', ' +  'SignedHeaders=' + signed_headers + ', ' + 'Signature=' + signature

    # The request can include any headers, but MUST include "host", "x-amz-date",
    # and (for this scenario) "Authorization". "host" and "x-amz-date" must
    # be included in the canonical_headers and signed_headers, as noted
    # earlier. Order here is not significant.
    # Python note: The 'host' header is added automatically by the Python 'requests' library.
    headers = {'x-amz-date':amzdate, 'Authorization':authorization_header}
    print(headers)

    # ************* SEND THE REQUEST *************
    request_url = endpoint + '?' + canonical_querystring

    print('\nBEGIN REQUEST++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
    print('Request URL = ' + request_url)
    r = requests.get(request_url, headers=headers)

    print('\nRESPONSE++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
    print('Response code: %d\n' % r.status_code)
    print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you didn't set up AWS Secret Access Key properly.

Solution:

1. Go to IAM section of your AWS account and select user or create one.
2. Assign **specific roles** needed for the project.
3. Navigate to Security credentials tab in your user account.
4. Select existing key or create new one and find AWS Secret Access Key.
5. You can setup AWS Secret Access Key as environmental varialbe in your system or in code.